# How to match newline and seven spaces in Powershell regex?

Tags: regex, powershell

Consider the following `html` snippet:

```
...
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      <div>    
        <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>
        <div class="bar">Name of the attachment (23 KB)</div>
...
```

If `<div class="foo">Attachments:</div>` is present in the html, I need to match the attachment name (there can be more, all of the `bar` class, each attachment in its own div). I have problems matching this because:

(1) I cannot get newline matching to work

(2) I am unable to match the 8 leading spaces before the `bar` div

```
$pattern = <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>\n^[ \t]+<div class="bar">(.*?)</div>
$matches = [regex]::matches($content, $pattern)

Write-Host ($matches[0])
```

The desired match would be `Name of the attachment (23 KB)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\n^` is either redundant or destructive, depending on whether the multiline modifier `m` is set.

Comment: What is the actual value of `$content`? Does it contain an array of lines or a single multiline string? In case of the former you need `^[ \t]+...`, in case of the latter you need `\n[ \t]+...`.

Answer (score 1):

Multiline regex can be easier to construct (IMHO) if you do it in a here string.  The newlines become part of the literal match.

```
$Text = 
@'
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      <div>    
        <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>
        <div class="bar">Name of the attachment (23 KB)</div>
'@

$regex= 
@'
(?ms)<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      <div>    
        <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>
        <div class="bar">(.+)</div>
'@

$text -match $regex > $null

$matches[1]

Name of the attachment (23 KB)
```

Edit: Per the comments, you're trying to extract multiple instances from the text, use the `[regex]::matches()` static method:

```
$Text = 
@'
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
      <div>    
        <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>
        <div class="bar">Name of the attachment (23 KB)</div>
....
        <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>
        <div class="bar">Name of the other attachment (23 KB)</div>
'@

$regex= 
@'
(?ms)   <div class="foo">Attachments:</div>
        <div class="bar">(.+?)</div>
'@

[regex]::Matches($Text,$regex) |
 foreach { $_.groups[1].value }

Name of the attachment (23 KB)
Name of the other attachment (23 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna propose another approach.
You could treat the HTML as xml and filter the data from the 'bar' class items .

something like this :

```
PS>[xml]$h='<html><body><div><div class="foo">Attachments: </div><div class="bar">Name of the attachment (23 KB) </div></div></body></html>'
PS>$h.html.body.div.div | ?{ $_.class -eq 'bar'} |select -Expand "#text" 
Name of the attachment (23 KB)
```

---

edit after your comments :

```
[xml]$h=@"
<html><body><div>
<div class="foo">Attachments: </div>
<div class="bar">Name of the attachment (23 KB) </div>
<div class="bar">file2 (3 KB) </div>
<div class='test'>aa</div>
<div class="bar">sfdfsd</div>
<div class="bar">sdfsdf</div>
<div class="foo">Attachments: </div>
<div class="bar">fileB1 (2 KB) </div>
</div></body></html>
"@

$cpt=0
$res=New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

#add each div to the ordered dictionary
$h.html.body.div.div |%{
        $res.add($cpt,@{"class"=$_.class;"text"=$_.'#text'})
$cpt++
}

$lastClass=''
(0.. ($res.count-1))|%{
    if($res[$_].class -ne 'bar' -and $res[$_].class -ne $lastClass){
    $lastClass=$res[$_].class
    $lastText=$res[$_].text
    }

    if($lastClass -eq 'foo' -and $lastText -eq 'Attachments: ' -and $res[$_].text -ne 'Attachments: '  -and $res[$_].class -eq 'bar' ){
        $res[$_].text 
    }
}
```

outputs :

```
PS>.\test.ps1                   
Name of the attachment (23 KB)  
file2 (3 KB)                    
fileB1 (2 KB)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that approach won't work because the actual file contains many divs of class `bar`. I need the `bar` div that follows after the `foo` div with "Attachments:" inline.